# Non-capturing group matching whitespace boundaries in JavaScript regex

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, word-boundaries

I have this function that finds whole words and should replace them. It identifies spaces but should not replace them, ie, not capture them.

```
function asd (sentence, word) {
     str = sentence.replace(new RegExp('(?:^|\\s)' + word + '(?:$|\\s)'), "*****");
     return str;
};
```

Then I have the following strings:

```
var sentence = "ich mag Äpfel";
var word = "Äpfel";
```

The result should be something like:

```
"ich mag *****"
```

and NOT:

```
"ich mag*****"
```

I'm getting the latter.

How can I make it so that it identifies the space but ignores it when replacing the word?

At first this may seem like a duplicate but I did not find an answer to this question, that's why I'm asking it.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put back the matched whitespaces by using a *capturing* group (rather than a *non-capturing* one) with a replacement backreference in the replacement pattern, and you may also leverage a lookahead for the right whitespace boundary, which is handy in case of consecutive matches:

```js
function asd (sentence, word) {
     str = sentence.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\s)' + word + '(?=$|\\s)'), "$1*****");
     return str;
};
var sentence = "ich mag Äpfel";
var word = "Äpfel";
console.log(asd(sentence, word));
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1YYyLW/1).

**Details**

- `(^|\s)` - Group 1 (later referred to with the help of a `$1` placeholder in the replacement pattern): a capturing group  that matches either start of string or a whitespace
- `Äpfel` - a search word
- `(?=$|\s)` - a positive lookahead that requires the end of string or whitespace immediately to the right of the current location.

**NOTE**: If the `word` can contain special regex metacharacters, [escape them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/3832970):

```
function asd (sentence, word) {
     str = sentence.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\s)' + word.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + '(?=$|\\s)'), "$1*****");
     return str;
};
```

Comment: do you know how can I make it so that it accounts words that start with an hyphen instead of beginning of string or whitespace?

example : find and replace "studio" for "****" in "ich gehe ins fitness-studio"

Comment: @N.Car You may add it to the left boundary: `(^|\\s)` -> `(^|[-\\s])`. It will be more problematic if you decide to implement the Unicode word boundary since the best way will be to use XRegExp (if you plan to support all browsers).